# flexjson.JSONDeserializer.use doesn't convert correctly

Tags: java, json, spring-roo

I'm trying to use flexjson to convert the following json string into a java object:

```
{"inboundDataNotification": {
    "callbackData": "12345",
    "inboundData": {
        "message": "Hello World",
        "messageId": "mes1234"
    }
}}
```

Using the following method:

```
import flexjson.JSONDeserializer;

@RooJavaBean @RooToString @RooJson(fromJsonArrayMethod="", toJsonArrayMethod="", toJsonMethod="") public class InboundData {

    private String messageId;

    private String message;

    public static InboundSMSMessage fromJsonToInboundSMSMessage(String json) {
        return new JSONDeserializer<InboundSMSMessage>().use(null, InboundSMSMessage.class).deserialize(json);
    }      }
```

All fields are null after this method is invoked. Any ideas what to change here?